# React question - how do you control the state of specific 'tiles' within a grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a grid-based react website. It utilises a 4x4 grid, containing 16 square 'tiles'[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVjgR.jpg).
Anyway, I want to be able to enter text and alter the state of 9 of these tiles (the blue ones in the image) - so what's the best way to to do this? Create a seperate component dealing with all 9 tiles, or do I have to create a component for each of the 9 tiles? Also below is code from my main grid component.
Thanks y'all!

```
render(){
return(
    <div className = 'grid-position'>
    <div className ='grid'>
        <div className = 'box date0'></div>
        <div className = 'box date1'>Week Starting: <br/>1st June</div>
        <div className = 'box date2'>Week Starting:</div>
        <div className = 'box date3'>Week Starting:</div>
        <div className = 'box task1'>Clean Kitchen</div>
        <div className = 'box card1'></div>
        <div className = 'box card2'></div>
        <div className = 'box card3'></div>
        <div className = 'box task2'>Buy flat supplies</div>
        <div className = 'box card4'></div>
        <div className = 'box card5'></div>
        <div className = 'box card6'></div>
        <div className = 'box task3'>Wash dishtowels</div>
        <div className = 'box card7'></div>
        <div className = 'box card8'></div>
        <div className = 'box card9'></div>
    </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a generic component representing one of the 9 boxes.

Then in your parent you'd manage the state of those 9 boxes in an array and render them by looping over that array.

Hooks

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [boxValues, setBoxValues] = useState(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    {boxValues.map((boxText, idx) => <ChildComponent key={`${boxText}-${idx}`} text={boxText} idx={idx} />}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

function ChildComponent({text, idx}){
  return (
    <div className={`box-card-${idx}`} />
  )
}
```

Since it's a simple example, they're mostly the same. The biggest difference is the state declaration:

Classes:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      boxValues: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    {this.state.boxValues.map((boxText, idx) => <ChildComponent key={`${boxText}-${idx}`} text={boxText} idx={idx} />}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for that - it makes a lot of sense! I'm not familiar with hooks though, any chance you could send through code in hook-less react?

Answer (score 0):

React basically focuses on component-based architecture to reduce the code complexity and reusability.

So the best way for you is to create a separate component for dealing with the tiles.

For reference read [this blog](https://blog.bitsrc.io/reusable-components-in-react-a-practical-guide-ec15a81a4d71) to understand it more deeply